# Does anyone recognize this bold serif font?

Tags: font-identification, serif

If anyone could help identity this bold serif font, it would help tremendously.

[image: 'Confessions of an advertising insider' written in the font]

Comment: The font and style look quite a lot like the font in the "Goodfellas" film poster - Bodoni I think (this is slightly less bold). It might well be based on that style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Arsis](http://www.myfonts.com/search/arsis/fonts/) was originally released [in 1939 by Linotype](http://www.linotype.com/search/arsis), so probably it was a prototype for the font in question:

[image]

Comment: After some research, I marked this as the answer (since it's the original typeface). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [WhatTheFont.com](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/), it looks like it is the [Onyx](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/onyx-mt/) typeface.

---

[image: Onyx Sample]

Comment: Thanks for some reason, I got different results when I tried whatthefont.com

Comment: As your answer was also correct I upvote it to compensate the V exchange....